# How to call `.update()` method in Sails.js?`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I'm using `sails.js v1` and `sails-postgresql`.

I need execute something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET balance -= 'amount' WHERE id = 'id';
```

I need to use `.usingConnection()`, so I can't use `.query()`.
How to make it?

Also what is best practices for avoiding 'race condition' in sails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for:

```
sails.sendNativeQuery
```

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/datastores/sendNativeQuery.md